# Сделать такой фон

Tags: html, css

Как сделать такой [фон](https://codepen.io/wbarlow/pen/NqLWXJ)?

пытался выдернуть лишь это

```
`@media (orientation: landscape) {
  /* put a blurred image in the background, just for pretty presentation */
  body::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background: url("адрес/1.jpeg") center/cover;
    -webkit-filter: blur(5vh);
            filter: blur(5vh);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
            transform: scale(1.2);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }`
```

Но не выходит.

Comment: Не выходит каменный цветок у Данилы-мастера, а в программировании такого термина нет. Есть желаемый результат и есть получаемый. Чем ваш получаемый результат отличается от желаемого?

Comment: тем что мои дивы ложатся под фон.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой пример - использовать для размытого фона псевдо-элемент `:before` и установить ему `z-index: -1`.

```css
body {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

body::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/8633/nature-tree-green-pine.jpg') no-repeat center center / cover;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  filter: blur(5px);
  z-index: -1;
}

.content {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: хороший, добротный ответ (+) А чего сам не стимулируешь автора вопроса. Вот плюсанул бы и он в ответ тоже самое сделал, а рейтинга достаточного нет у него и он при всём желании не может плюсануть. :)